# SQL : table relationship depends on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am novice at SQL using Postgres, and have been looking for this answer for a few days.

I have a table called identification

```
| id | name | type |
```

A type is a driving licence, passport, national id card etc.

If the type is a driving licence, the relationship should be with the driving licence table

```
| id | first_name | last_name | driving_licence_number |
```

If the type is passport, the relationship should be with the passport_table.

The way I can describe it in pseudo code is

```
if (type == 0) join with driving licence table

if (type == 1) join with passport table etc.
```

What would be the best way to model this, so I can easily query the identification table, and retrieve the correct info?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question about "modeling".  You seem to already have a data structure.  You can query these tables using logic such as:

```
select . . .
from identifications i left join
     driving_licenses dl
     on i.type = 0 and
        i.name = dl.driving_licence_number left join
     passports p
     on i.type = 1 and
        i.name = p.passport;
```

This is definitely a reasonable data model.  However, Postgres supports [*inheritance*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html), which might be appropriate for this use-case.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I apologise if my question didn't make much sense, but you somehow figured out what I was trying to say. I'm trying to get head around all the terminology.

Comment: i do have a similar situation, can u please explain how u did it ??